# How to get proper tabular output like the mysql command line from a bash script

Tags: bash

I am querying a database from a bash script using following query:-

```
Output = echo "$QUERY_STR" | mysql -h $DB_HOST -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME
```

it gives me the required output which I save in a Variable

However when I echo `$output` I do not get proper formatted output like in command line of mysql query.

Read one of the post to use `-t` in the query however for large data set it does not give proper output.

To work around it, I am saving the output in a .csv file.

Answer (score 3):

To maintain all the whitespace that is indeed kept in the variable's value, it is crucial to double-quote the variable:

```
echo "$output"
```

Also, you cannot have whitespace around the equal sign in a variable assignment:

```
output=$(mysql ... <<< "$QUERY_STR")
```