# Preserving original format of output from CGI script while displaying in HTML

Tags: html, mysql, bash, cgi

I am trying to  write a cgi script which reads data from a MySQL database using mysql query and stores the data in a variable. The variable output is displayed using HTML

To preserve the original format of MySQL Query output , I have used "" character while displaying value of a variable as suggested here .
[How to get proper tabular output like the mysql command line from a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215495/how-to-get-proper-tabular-output-like-the-mysql-command-line-from-a-bash-script)

But it looks like the original formatting is not preserved while displaying value of the variable in HTML.

This is the output from MySQL Query

```
mysql -uroot -ptest -D mysql -e "select host,db from db " ;
```

`+-----------+---------+
| host      | db      |
+-----------+---------+
| www       | test    |
| web       | test    |
| localhost | bugs    |
| localhost | hrm     |
| localhost | ohrm    |
| localhost | otrs    |
+-----------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Same output looks as follows when displayed using HTML

`host db www test web test localhost bugs localhost hrm localhost ohrm localhost otrs`

The HTML code snippet for above output is as follows

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo "Content-type: text/html"
 echo ""

 echo "<html>"
 echo "<body>"`

 var=`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p redhat -D mysql -e "select host,db from db;"`
 echo "$var"
 echo "</body>"
 echo "</html>"
```

How can I preserve the format from original output in HTML . Please suggest.

Comment: Try changing the content mime type from `text/html` to `text/plain`.

Comment: But there is another issue here . The HTML tags are not processed after changing content type  text/plain

Comment: Yes, `text/plain` instructs the browser to treat it as a plaintext and not process any HTML in it. I just posted an answer for desired HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `-H` or `--html` command line parameter while doing the mysql query to get HTML table output. Use the `text/html` mime type with this.

Modifying your query:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p redhat -H -D mysql -e "select host,db from db;"
```